# SQL Query: Display the Staff Id, fname, last name, Malpractice Date, Malpractice Desc for all doctors that have had more than 2 cases in the last year

Tags: sql, group-by

I have tried to solve this for a few hours and I am close but haven't been able to get it to work. Here is what I have now:

```
SELECT 
    Doctor_ID, s.firstname,s.lastname
FROM 
    MALPRACTICE M
INNER JOIN  
    STAFF S ON S.STAFF_ID = M.DOCTOR_ID
WHERE 
    Malpractice_date >= '01/01/2017'
GROUP BY
    doctor_id, s.firstname, s.lastname
```

When I add `malpractice_date` and `malpractice_desc` to the select statement, it yields no result. What am I missing?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is close, but the point of `group by` is to use aggregate functions such as `sum`, `avg`, `min`, `max` and so on. You then can use `having` (which is a kind of `where` *after* group by) on `sum`. This works for at least SQLite:

```
create table staff (staff_id, firstname, lastname);
create table malpractice (doctor_id, malpractice_date);

insert into staff values (1, 'Dr', 'Phil');
insert into staff values (2, 'Doc', 'Hollywood');
insert into staff values (3, 'Doctor', 'Dolittle');
insert into malpractice values (1, '2017-02-28');
insert into malpractice values (1, '2018-01-20');
insert into malpractice values (1, '2018-02-12');
insert into malpractice values (1, '2018-03-01');
insert into malpractice values (1, '2018-04-22');
insert into malpractice values (2, '2016-03-01');
insert into malpractice values (2, '2017-12-01');
insert into malpractice values (2, '2018-04-22');

select m.doctor_id, s.firstname, s.lastname, sum(1) malpractices_last_year
from malpractice m
join staff s on s.staff_id=m.doctor_id
where strftime('%J','now') - strftime('%J',m.malpractice_date) <= 365
group by m.doctor_id, s.firstname, s.lastname
having sum(1) > 2;
```

Test this SQL yourself, or change it, at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/600da/11

(I interpreted *in the last year* as being within the last 365 days)

One thing: If your database stores dates as strings (not recommended, unless you're using SQLite, where it's necessary), which `Malpractice_date >= '01/01/2017'` suggests, then you should at least make the dates sortable by putting year before month and month before day: 22nd April 2018 is then `2018-04-22`.

You didn't mention which database system you use, and they are notorious for treating dates differently. In SQLite `strftime` is often used for "doing math" on date strings, on other databases other functions will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

try all of your attributes prepended with your aliases s and m